# What does "PERFORMANCE WARNING: Some textures are unrenderable" mean in Chrome?

Tags: webgl

In my WebGL, in the JavaScript console, I see the warning

```
PERFORMANCE WARNING: Some textures are unrenderable.
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 10):

WebGL must enforce OpenGL ES 2.0 behavior and prevent WebGL apps from accessing data they don't have access to. To do this WebGL implementations have to validate many things including that all the textures that will be read from are readable according to the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec with no extensions.

So, at every draw, they have to check if all the textures meet all the required criteria which includes checking that that each texture is "texture complete", if it's a cubemap that it is "cube complete" and "mipmap cube complete", if it's non-power-of-2 dimensions that texture filtering is set correctly, etc... If any of these conditions are not met the WebGL implementation will substitute a transparent black texture so that behavior will be spec compliant and consistent across devices.

These checks are expensive so a shortcut a WebGL implementation can take is to track if any textures are unrenderable. If no textures are unrenderable then no checking is needed at draw time. The warning above is that some textures are unrenderable which is basically telling you WebGL has to do all this expensive checking. If you make sure all your textures are renderable WebGL can skip this check and your app may run faster.

For definitions of "texture complete", "cube complete", etc... see [OpenGL ES 2.0 spec section 3.7.10](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf)

Comment: If you are using Three.js, it can be caused by wrong usage of THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture. You should wait for loadTexture callback, before adding mesh with this texture to the scene.

Comment: @dIsoVi Bravo! All the examples I've seen so far don't use the callback, so I didn't even know it was asynchronous. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the details of Three.JS but usually rather than waiting for a texture to load before adding a mesh to scene I create a 1x1 pixel texture and load the image into that texture. That way I can draw the mesh immediately since a 1x1 pixel texture meets all rendering requirements. When the image has loaded I'll update the texture with the image data and then set filtering and/or generate mips. That way I can start rendering immediately. It's up to you if that solution fits your app.

Answer (score 3):

This could also be the result of a bug in Chrome 28: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242321 I got this message even when my WebGL script wasn't using any textures at all.

It was fixed in Chrome 29.